# Is wifi speed different for Mac and Windows?

Tags: wireless-networking, speed

So I have a PC with Windows 10 and a MacBook Pro. My ISP is FIOS by Verizon with a 200Mbps plan(Not sure if it's Megabytes per sec or megabits per sec... If someone can help me get educated on this I'll be forever grateful.)
I tried to check my internet connection by speedtest.net website. The results are just crazy. I'll share it below,

1. Wifi on PC - The download/upload speed is 33.45/27.35 Mbps ping being 11ms. My Laptop is a HP Notebook with Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11 bgn Wifi adapter, it works only on the 2.4 GHz frequency band. Wi-fi status at
   Control Panel> Network and internet> Network Connections says the speed at 72.2 Mbps.
2. Ethernet on PC - The download/upload speed is 94.78/93.71 Mbps ping being 5ms. Same Laptop as above,  Wi-fi status at
   Control Panel> Network and internet> Network Connections says the speed at 100 Mbps.
3. Mac - The download/upload speed is 298.63/224.08 Mbps ping being 3ms.

So as you can tell that the speed difference is almost 10 times between my PC wifi and Mac. Is there anything that I can do to increase the speed on my PC upto the speed of Mac as I do most of my work on PC only. Waiting for you responses. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you measuring the speed on the Mac? Is it WiFi or wired?

Comment: *"Not sure if it's Megabytes per sec or megabits per sec..."* -- The lower case 'b' is usually used for "bits", while uppercase "B" for bytes. Internet speeds are almost always advertised in mega**bits** per second (Mbps) since the measurement of the actual transferred *bytes* per second is a lot more complex and differs between devices and addresses due to a lot of factors.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It is Wifi.

Comment: @Romen So I think the connections like the internet speed for instance is in megabits per sec. Is it valid for all speeds on the internet or just in case for speed offered by ISPs.

Comment: Almost all network speeds are measured in "Mbps", and this is well established as the correct way to write "Mega**bits** per second". Speedtest.net also reports in Megabits per second. I began to mention above that measuring the number of *bytes* per second is actually quite complex. Errors in the signal can lead to a whole packet being lost because a single bit was flipped. Which means the packet needs to be re-sent and the total number of bits used to send those bytes are way higher.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, you're getting the speeds your hardware is capable of. Your HP notebook's Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11b/g/n 2.4GHz-only adapter is only a 1x1 (i.e. SISO, not MIMO), and it supports Bluetooth so it probably signals 40MHz-intolerance on Wi-Fi to leave more room in the 2.4GHz band for Wi-Fi to work. This combination of only being capable of a single stream of N-style modulation on a 20MHz-wide channel means its top signaling rate is 72.2, which after protocol overhead means throughput of up to only 50Mbps under ideal conditions.

If a laptop design is so old/cheap as to use a super cheap wireless card like that, I wouldn't be surprised if it went with a cheap 10/100 Ethernet instead of gigabit-capable Ethernet. TCP/IP over standard Ethernet is 94.3% efficient, so you're seeing the max throughput that 100Mbps Ethernet can provide.

Every MacBook since 2013 supports 2-3 stream 802.11ac with 80MHz wide channels, meaning throughput up to 600Mbps under good conditions. So the fact that your MBP is seeing the full speed you're paying for from Verizon sounds about right.

tl;dr: Your MBP's networking hardware is nearly 10x faster than your HP's, so you're getting the speeds your hardware is capable of.

Answer (score 3):

@spiff answer is correct. This answer seeks to focus on how to improve things in simple terms -

The performance bottlenecks are due to old and crappy hardware(Realtek is bottom of the barrel in terms of quality and performance).

For best performance (within reason and for your usage case), yoy want to connect your laptop to your router using **gigabit** Ethernet.  At the moment you appear to be restricted to 100 megabit which could be a hardware limitation, fault or a driver issue. If you look at the device settings and find the name of the Ethernet controller, we can advise better - but my guess is its a hardware limit (802.11n wifi...). The cheapest solution is likely to be to get a decent gigabit USB - Ethernet adaptor and use this. (You will likel have a bottleneck of USB2 preventing gigabit throughput, but you should be able to achieve  > 200 megabit which is what you are paying for for your network connection.

The alternative is to get a quality WIFI adaptor. This is going to be a lot more expensive and provide more variable performance with no guarantees. You will need an adaptor with 802.11ac support, and you will want something with more then 1 aerial.

With respect to speed, you are almost certainly paying for 200 megabits/sec - not megabytes/sec.  I've never seen a network connection sold in megabytes, and the stupid convention of megabits has been arround since the earliest modems and serial ports. Also, a 200 megabyte/sec connection would be extremely expensive - even just in terms if routers and networking that could take advantage of it.

Another consideration should be the specs of your laptop.  You may find that the laptop is to old and slow to make beneficial use of a high speed network connection - with bottlenecks like HDDs and slow CPUs, I would not be surprised if -in practice - your network upgrade did not translate to a significant performance upgrade.

Answer (score -3):

I am by no means an expert but, there is two things you can try.

1. Forget/Disconnect from the WI-FI on both and run the Speedtest again
2. Restart your router and run the test again.

Like I said, I am in no way an expert. But, I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Tried both of your suggestions already but to no avail.

Comment: Do you get the speeds you are advertised on other devices. If so, then I am stumped unfortunately. If not, contact the ISP.